# Is there a way to do in-place C macro expansion in VS code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, macros, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.34 and ms-vscode.cpptools 0.24.1. In a C file, when I hover over a statement containing a C macro, VS Code is kind enough to expand the macro in a hover box.

I can select this expanded piece of code and then manually replace the macro's 'call' side with it. But I was wondering if there is a way in vscode or in one of its extensions to do this macro expansion in-place, e.g. using some key shortcut.  From what I have read from the documentation, I think you cannot do this with ms-vscode.cpptools alone.

It would be a nice bonus if back-slash line breaks were substituted with actual new lines in the in-place expension.

Comment: the preprocesser step of the compilation does this.  so you could simply only run the preprocesser step

Comment: Nope, that will preprocess every macro. I only want to expend one macro and let additional nested macro's in this one alone. Furthermore using the gcc preprocessor's output is also a lot of work: first call gcc -E ... capture the output. Clean up the line stuff and remove potential duplicate defines etc and finally you have to temporarily replace the current source file with the cleaned preprocessed output.

Comment: @ArisKoning, In the latest release of VScode, it's supporting the Macro expansion.Ref:https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4183